# How can free tensor on GPU in libtorch?

Tags: c++, libtorch

```
for(auto &batch: *dataloader){
    const auto& floatInput = batch.data.to(torch::kCUDA);
    const auto& target = batch.target.to(torch::kCUDA);
    
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeByte, &totalByte);
    cout << freeByte << " / " << totalByte <<  endl;

    floatInput.to(torch::kCPU);
    target.to(torch::kCPU);
    c10::cuda::CUDACachingAllocator::emptyCache();
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeByte, &totalByte);
    cout << freeByte << " / " << totalByte << endl;
}
```

I want to free GPU when moving tensor from GPU to CPU, but GPU memory isn't removed.
If I just call `float.to(torch::kCPU)` and `cudaMemGetInfo`, GPU memory remain the same as before.

I think `float.to(torch::kCPU)` does not free GPU memory.

I want to keep the value of `floatInput` and `target` on CPU.

Comment: Your question assumes that Torch allocates and deallocates memory every time you upload or remove data. Wouldn't it make more sense for Torch to just reuse the GPU memory next time you upload data?

Comment: I agree with you. I also think It is more efficient to reuse the GPU memory. However, I have out of memory problem, so I want to deallocate memory when one batch step ends. Is there any way to manually deallocate memory of `floatInput` and `target`?